# Get permission ID of suspended user in Google Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the Drive API to inspect my Google Apps Domain.  I successfully create a service but fail trying to get the permission IDs of all my users when I have a suspended user on the domain.  Using my get_about function results in a 401 Unauthorized : Invalid Credentials.  Is there anyway to get around that error? Should I create a different type of service somehow? Right now I am forced to skip that user.

```
#Passing in a already created user service
def get_about(service):
    return service.about().get().execute()
```

Here's where i create the service:

```
class DriveService(object):
    """
    The main entry class to constructing the google drive api client service
    We wrap the service so it can be used as normal but with some error
    handling provided
    """

    raw_service = None
    http = None
    auth_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

    def __init__(self, user_email):
        key_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0],
                                 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PEM_FILE)
        with open(key_file_path, 'rb') as f:
            key = f.read()

        credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                                                key,
                                                scope=self.auth_scope,
                                                prn=user_email)
        self.user_email = user_email
        self.http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        try:
            self.raw_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=self.http,
                             requestBuilder=BackoffHttpRequest,
                             )
        except:
            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return getattr(self.raw_service, attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way around this. The account is disabled and you won't be able to use JWT assertion to do anything useful with it.

As of now you need to xfer ownership of user files to another account prior to deleting/suspending them. Pull a list of all users > all files of all users > all permissions of all files. From there you can parse the permission ids locally for the said username to get the data you're after. It takes about 40 minutes to pull that data in my environment. I believe this is what the 3rd party drive apps (CloudLock and General Audit Tool and Flashpanel) do in order to get useful data. Probably not the answer you wanted.

An API that pulls global drive results without the need of assertion would be extremely helpful in this situation. Alternatively being able to query permissions by something other than the fileID would be good. Hopefully this is on the roadmap.